# Calculate calendar days Rails where start time is 09:00 AM

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I appreciate your help with the following:

I am active in the rental industries. The idea is that a customer pays for the amount of calendar days, whereby the **calendar day should be from 09:01 AM to 09:00 AM the next day**.

Note that a customer can select a pickup date and pickup time from the datetimepicker.

To calculate the number of calendar days, i use the following variable.

```
"num_of_calendar_days = ((return_date.end_of_day - pickup_date.beginning_of_day)/ 86400).to_i + 1"
```

Obviously, this is not a great solution as the day is now starting at 00:00 until 23:59.

Can you help me out with the code to fix this? Some way to add 9 hours to the beginning and the end of the day helper?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @jeroen, is there any impact calculating the calendar days from the beginning of the start day to the end of the last day?

Also, we can set the time of the days to 09:00AM and then subtract the days.

Comment: Hi Oseme, yes. Let's say someone picks up the product (car) at 1 PM on Monday, and returns it at 8 AM Tuesday. In that case, the calendar days should amount to 1. If on the other hand, the person returns the car at 10AM Tuesday, the calendar days should be two.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution will be to set the time of the pickup date to **09:01 AM** and then set the return date's time to the actual return time. We can then simply subtract the datetimes to get the actual days and add one extra day to accommodate for the pickup day.

```rb
    pickup_time = "09:01" # should be set to start of business day + 1 minute
    return_time = "10:00"

    pickup_time_parts = pickup_time.split(":")
    return_time_parts = return_time.split(":")

    pickup_date = "07-11-2020".to_datetime.change(hour: pickup_time_parts[0].to_i, min: pickup_time_parts[1].to_i)
    return_date = "08-11-2020".to_datetime.change(hour: return_time_parts[0].to_i, min: return_time_parts[1].to_i)

    num_of_calendar_days = (return_date - pickup_date).to_i + 1

    # print out the result here
    puts "Number of Calendar Days: " + num_of_calendar_days.to_s
```

Comment: @JeroenSwart, I am glad to have helped out :) . Please you can go ahead and mark this answer as accepted. Thanks